# What is the best way to do multi-dimensional indexing with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am trying to do some indexing on a 3D numpy array.
Basically I have an array `phi` which has shape `(F,A,D)`; for example `(5, 3, 7)`. Generated, for example as follows:

```
F=5; A=3; D=7; phi = np.random.random((F,A,D))
```

My goal is to be able to index over `A` and `D`, with a 2D array such as `[[0,1,2],[5,5,6]]`, which means take the values indexed by 0 in the 3rd dimension, for the the first position in `A`, the values indexed by 1 in the 3rd dimension for the second position of `A` and so on. The result should have a shape that is `(F,A,2)` or `(F,2,A)`.

This would be equivalent to manually cycling all the values of the "indexer array" such as:

```
phi[:,0,0]; phi[:,1,1]; phi[:,2,2]
phi[:,0,5]; phi[:,1,5]; phi[:,2,6]
```

Intuitively I would do something like `phi[:,:,[[0,1,2],[3,3,3]]]`, but it's shape ends up being `(5, 3, 2, 3)`.

Any ideas on how to obtain the correct result?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Bring an easy example and tell us what the output should look like

Comment: @plonser: ok, adding an edit...

Comment: @plonser: added the external loop expansion as exemplification

Comment: Is your expected shape a typo? Shouldn't it be `(F,2,A)` given your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
phi[:,range(A),[[0,1,2],[5,5,6]]]
```

Your attempt

```
phi[:,:,[[0,1,2],[5,5,6]]]
```

takes the values along the third dimension for every values of the first two dimensions, therefore you end up with a shape of `(5,3,2,3)`.

However, according to your example you want a continous increase in the second dimension which is accomplished in my code by `range(A)` and numpy's broadcasting.